# Is java run-time environment free to use whatever size it wants for primitive data types?

Tags: java

I was going through the book "Java-The Complete Reference" and I came across a sentence which says that

> "The width of an integer type should not be thought of as the amount of storage it consumes,but rather as the behavior it defines for variables and expressions of that type. The java run-time environment is free to use whatever size it wants,as long as the types behave as you declared them".

Does this mean the java is free to choose the size of the integer data type which is typically of 4 bytes?

Comment: Java defines four integer types i.e., long , int, short, byte. So don't be confused with integer types and int. In java int is of 32 bits.

Comment: Yeah I am aware of that but I am not able to understand what that sentence actually means.Can you please explain me that?

Comment: @AsteriskNinja So you are saying that when we typecast for example from int to long,java decides to use long width which is of 64 bits?

Comment: @SaiSankalp That's what the specification requires. The JVM is always free to use wider types, but it would be wasteful.

Comment: @EJP Yeah I got it thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "The width of an integer type should not be thought of as the amount
> of storage it consumes,

A JVM may *store* a Java 16-bit `short` in 32 bits on 32-bit implementations to improve performance...

> but rather as the behavior it defines for variables and expressions of
> that type.

... but it will *behave* like a 16-bit signed two's complement integer, regardless of how it's stored in memory.

> The java run-time environment is free to use whatever size
> it wants,as long as the types behave as you declared them".

If a program needs to run on any JVM, all JVMs need to treat the program and its integers in the same way. But how the JVM is implemented doesn't matter to a Java developer, which allows for optimizations that are specific to the architecture.

Comment: Arjan’s explanation is very well-said and correct. I'll just add that this is the basic idea behind all of the specifications for the Java language and for the JVM: *Define the required behaviors but leave the implementation details to the implementer.* There have been many implementations of Java over the years, all behaving the same but varying quite dramatically as to what's “under the hood”.